# Create a buffer in a dataframe based on multiple columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe

```
EGID    Start_date     End_Date    Consumption    Number_day

  1      2019-01-01    2019-05-28       30        152
  1      2019-06-05    2019-07-31       40        60
  1      2019-08-01    2019-09-31       40        0
  1      2019-02-11    2019-04-14       60        60 
  2      2019-02-11    2019-04-14       60        60 
  2      2019-08-01    2019-09-31       40        200
  3      2019-01-01    2019-05-28       30        200
  3      2019-06-05    2019-07-31       40        150
  3      2019-08-01    2019-09-31       40        60
  3      2019-09-31    2019-12-31       50        60
```

Expected Output:

```
EGID    Start_date     End_Date    Consumption    Number_day

  1      2019-01-01    2019-07-31       70        212
  1      2019-08-01    2019-09-31       40        0
  1      2019-02-11    2019-04-14       60        60 
  2      2019-02-11    2019-09-31       100       260
  3      2019-01-01    2019-07-31       70        350
  3      2019-08-01    2019-12-31       90        120
```

I would like to sum the consumption and the number of days if it's the same EGID (string). However, if the row of the number of days is above 350 or equal to 0 then it should stop summing (even if it's the same EGID- see EGID 1). Then, if the total of the sum of the number_days is above 350 then it should stop summing (see EGID 3). Finally the end_date of the row should be the last one that have been summed.

Someone helped me out and we did this but unfortunately the sum of the number of days could be above 350 since it summed everything with the same EGID.

```
df['Consumption2'] = (df['Number_day'] < 350) * df['Consumption']  
df['Number_day2'] = (df['Number_day'] < 350) * df['Number_day']
df.groupby(['EGID'])[['Start_date', 'End_Date', 'Consumption2', 'Number_day2']].agg({'Start_date':'min', 'End_Date':'max', 'Consumption2':'sum', 'Number_day2':'sum'})
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post the expected output? Since it is not very clear from your description.

Comment: Hey, the expected output is written :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and if the results are not the desired please adjust the current question to include those cases aling with the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd #import library

# i am assuming that your dataframe name is df
df = pd.DataFrame({'EGID':['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3'], 
             'Start_date':['2019-01-01', '2019-06-05', '2019-08-01', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-11',
                          '2019-08-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-06-05', '2019-08-01', '2019-09-31'],
             'End_Date':['2019-05-28', '2019-07-31', '2019-09-31', '2019-04-14', '2019-04-14',
                        '2019-09-31', '2019-05-28', '2019-07-31', '2019-09-31', '2019-12-31'], 
             'Consumption':[30, 40, 40, 60, 60, 40, 30, 40, 40, 50], 
             'Number_day':[152, 60, 0, 60, 60, 200, 200, 150, 60, 60]})


def counter_limits(x, lower_limit = 0, upper_limit=350):
    """
    Function that takes a list or pandas series and returns a list integers that increment 
    when cumulative sum is reached or the element is the lower limit
    """
    result = []
    cummulative = 0
    counter = 0
    prev_el = -1
    for el in x:
        cummulative += el
        if (cummulative > upper_limit) or (el == lower_limit) or (prev_el == lower_limit):
            counter += 1
            cummulative = 0
            result.append(counter)
        else:
            result.append(counter)
        prev_el = el
    return result

df['key'] = df.groupby(['EGID'])['Number_day'].transform(counter_limits)

df2 = pd.concat([
    df.groupby(['EGID', 'key'])[['Start_date', 'End_Date']].last(),
    df.groupby(['EGID', 'key'])[['Consumption', 'Number_day']].sum()
    ], axis=1).reset_index().drop(columns='key')

df2
```

Comment: The code works well. I have a tiny problem. When, there is number of days equal to 349, the code will still sum the number of days and the consumption. I thought cummulative > upper_limit will avoid the issue but unfortunately it doesn't. I added this condition (el+prev_el>=upper_limit)What do you think? –